# How to include a multiple words string in URL for redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am saving a category in rails. Would like to pass a message if the saving successes with msg=successful, and it worked. However there is an error saying bad URI if multiple words message is included, such as msg=category saved successfully or msg='category saved successfully'.

The following code is working:

```
 if @category.save!

    redirect_to "/view_handler?index=1&msg=successfully&url=#{categories_path}"  

  else
    render :action => "new" 
  end
```

But this does not, with single quote or without:

```
 if @category.save!

    redirect_to "/view_handler?index=1&msg=category saved successfully&url=#{categories_path}"  

  else
    render :action => "new" 
  end
```

Here is the code for view_handler:

```
  def view_handler
    index  = params[:index].to_i
    url = params[:url]
    msg = params[:msg]
    if index == 0   #backword
      session[:page_step] -= 1  #step_back
      url = session[('page' + session[:page_step].to_s).to_sym]      
    else  #forward
      session[:page_step] += 1 
      session[('page' + session[:page_step].to_s).to_sym] = url
    end

    #redirect to the page by url  
    if msg.nil?                                                         
      redirect_to url
    else
      redirect_to url, :notice => msg
    end   
  end
```

Any thoughts about the error? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the [URI::Escape](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/uri/1.9.2/frames) method.

So, for your example:

```
 redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=1&msg=category saved successfully&url=#{categories_path}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a PHP prorammer, maybe i'm wrong, but it seems a problem of encoding the url parameters. Try something like url_encode (something similar in ruby) on the phrase with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I probably would've done it like this.

```
redirect_to :controller => <controller_name>, :action => :view_handler,
  :msg => "category saved successfully", :url => categories_path, :index => 1
```